# Observable Collection is not being Updated (observable collection of strings inside an observable collection of class item)

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml, observablecollection

I have 2 classes named person and Remainder

Here is the remainder class details it contains an observable collection names zuids

```
        public string Description;
        public DateTime DateAndTime;
        public string dateandtime;
        public bool isCompleted;
        public ObservableCollection<string> zuids;
        public string channelId;
```

this is the person class

```
 public string zuid;
        public string name,email;
        public Remainder r { get; set; }
        public Person(string id,string name,string email)
        {
            this.zuid = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }
```

I just created this UI[image]

main page

```
public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
 public List<Remainder> Remainders = new List<Remainder>();

 public ObservableCollection<Remainder> RemaindersForMe = new ObservableCollection<Remainder>();
```

(these remainders for me section is being displayed on the right side list of remainder in the picture)

SO here from the flyout box i have a add button which adds users to the remainder, So when  i select name of some one from auto suggest box then their respective id gets updated into the remainders zuids observable collection. But when i add it is not being updated where as i tried to create the new remainder with the values of old one and the new remainders updated persons are displayed properly.

[image]
this is the autosuggestbox
here is my code

```
<Button Name="AddMorePeople" Content="+" CornerRadius="25" FontSize="20">
                                                        <Button.Flyout>
                                                            <Flyout>
                                                                <StackPanel >
                                                                    <AutoSuggestBox 
                                                                        Name="MyAutoSuggestBox1" 
                                                                        PlaceholderText="Search"  
                                                                        Width="150"
                                                                        SuggestionChosen="MyAutoSuggestBox1_SuggestionChosen"
                                                                        TextChanged="MyAutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
                                                                        PointerEntered="MyAutoSuggestBox_PointerEntered"
                                                                        Tag="{x:Bind RemainderId}"
                                                                     />
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </Flyout>
                                                        </Button.Flyout>
                                                    </Button>
```

this is the add button that is displayed in the picture, on clicking the add button an auto suggestion box opens

```
private void MyAutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var Auto = (AutoSuggestBox)sender;
            List<string> Suggestion;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Auto.Text))
                Suggestion = Peoplenames.Where(p=>p!="excludedname").ToList();
            else
                Suggestion = Peoplenames.Where(p => p.StartsWith(Auto.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && p!="excludedname" ).ToList();
            Auto.ItemsSource = Suggestion.ToArray();
            
        }
```

```
private void MyAutoSuggestBox1_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
        {
            int value = (int)sender.Tag;
            
            foreach(var i in RemaindersForMe.ToList())
            {
                if(i.RemainderId==value)
                {
                    foreach(var j in Persons)
                    {
                        if(j.name==args.SelectedItem.ToString())
                        {
                            i.zuids.Add(j.zuid);
                            //Testingbox.Text = i.zuids.Count.ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

in the testing box number of users are displaying properly but it is not updated in the remianders list.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example, at least XAML with bindings and initialization code.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev Hai I updated please take a look

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<string> zuids;` I dont see any code instanciating that obervable collection, was that code `i.zuids.Count.ToString()` throwing `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @OsSnehithAb remainders list XAML needed

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I am beginner , Please don't mind and can you look into this repository  https://github.com/snehith-1012/UWP-excercises

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko I might miss a lot please look into this https://github.com/snehith-1012/UWP-excercises

Comment: Let me help you!

Comment: knock me on skype: shakir_820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use INotifyProperyChanged to reflect the changes. Also you have to use x:Bind, Mode=TwoWay.